# Re-enable 16.04 LTS upgrade

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I have Ubuntu 15.10 and I refused by accident the 16.04 LTS upgrade. So, now when I launch `do-release-upgrade`, no new release where found and I cannot upgrade to 16.04 LTS.

I have also checked the content of the file `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgarde-available`:

```
New release '16.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

Is there a way to re-enable Ubuntu upgrade somewhere?

Comment: Did you try `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`? Make sure it says you are upgrading to 16.04 before you enter "y"!

Answer (score 1):

after reading the `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core` I have discover that the entry 15.10 has been removed on the `/var/lib/update-manager-lts`.

So, after add the correct entry, my upgrade is running...

Comment: but upgrade failed...

Comment: after restart and reboot it seems that the trick is done... sorry for the noise